# How to init this jQuery countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Found out about [this](http://1plusdesign.com/articles/add-countdown-timer-website/) cool jQuery countdown

which is initialized as such:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#countdown').countdown({until:$.countdown.UTCDate(-8, 2011,  1 - 1, 1), format: 'DHMS', layout:
            '<div id="timer">' + '<hr />'+
            '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_labels">'+
            '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'
    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea how must I config it to countdown until 14th of July, and to also until 18:00PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for that plugin is here: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

The snippet there is:

```
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
```

That makes it countdown to the next new year.  To count down to a particular date, set `newyear = new Date(2011, 12-1, 25)` (that's Christmas day).

So you could do:

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(2011, 07-1, 4)});
```

Comment: thanks! solved (at same time) with var dateString = "14.07.2011";
var dateParts = dateString.split(".");
var dt = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
what do you think is better?

Comment: I edited the answer to show what I would do.  It's unnecessary indirection to set it as a string, split the string and then use the parts to make a date...

Comment: i see, thanks again! but what if i would like to specify also at 18:00pm?